# iOS - Adding TabBarController ruined my custom AppDelgate.m for TableViews

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

Here is my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    EventsMasterViewController *firstViewController = (EventsMasterViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    EventDataController *_myEventsDataController = [[EventDataController alloc] init];
    firstViewController.myEventsDataController = _myEventsDataController;

    EventDataController *_upcomingEventsDataController = [[EventDataController alloc] init];
    firstViewController.upcomingEventsDataController = _upcomingEventsDataController;

    EventDataController *_bookmarkedEventsDataController = [[EventDataController alloc] init];
    firstViewController.bookmarkedEventsDataController = _bookmarkedEventsDataController;

    return YES;
}
```

This used to work great when my only views were a MasterViewController and a DetailViewController, embedded in a Navigation Controller.

Now I want to add a TabBarController. So I embedded the NavigationController into the TabBarController. But my delegate is throwing an error.

I really need to initialize 3 instances of my EventDataController as shown.

So I guess the question would be, "How do I grab the navigationController from the tabBarController programmatically so that I can add the EventsDataControllers to the firstViewController?"

**UPDATE**

Here is my error. I don't understand how setMyEventsDataController becomes a method on the UINavigationController.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setMyEventsDataController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UITabBarController` has to be the window's rootViewController. You then add each of the `UINavigationBarController`s as the `contentView`s of the tab bar.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive answer. I will look into this!

Comment: I'm having difficulty figuring out how to grab the MasterViewController from the NavigationController using what you mentioned. Can you point me towards a sample of this? I found that I'm able to do this in the `viewDidLoad` method of my EventsMasterViewController.h but shouldn't it belong in the AppDelegate?

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about. The code shows no UITabBarController, but you said that is what you want to use. If you want to use a UITabBarController in your app, it MUST be the rootViewController of your window, and you add everything else to that  (normally each tab will be a UINavigation controller but it need not be. So you are not going to grab anything - you are going to create the tab bar controller, keep a strong reference to it, makeit the window.rootViewController, then add your other views to it.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I added the tabBarController through the Storyboard successfully. What I need to do is instantiate my `EventDataController` by doing something like `myView.myEventsDataController = blah`

Answer (score -1):

```
EventsMasterViewController *firstViewController = (EventsMasterViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Because you set the firstViewController to the nav controller itself.

Comment: I'm not sure the syntax for grabbing the navigationController from inside the tabBarController. I attempted this: `UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;` and then `UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];` But I'm not really understanding if that is working correctly.